# KVM connection to a remote server (Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: server, gui, kvm-virtualization, openssh

I am trying to set up a VPS on my local network. So, I have installed an Ubuntu 18.04 server (without GUI) on a computer with IP address of 192.168.0.109. I used these commands to install KVM on the server

```
sudo apt-get install qemu-kvm libvirt-bin virtinst bridge-utils cpu-checker
sudo apt-get install virt-manager ssh-askpass-gnome --no-install-recommends
sudo systemctl enable libvirtd
sudo systemctl start libvirtd
```

I ran all these commands on the server, through ssh, from my desktop computer.
Now I want to run *Virtual Machine Manager* from other computer (desktop ubuntu with GUI) and remotely connect to the server. I get this error:

[image: permission denied error askpass doesn't find file]

I am not sure if it is possible to connect to Ubuntu server (without GUI) or not. If yes, how I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The error message tells you that you need `openssh-askpass`, or more precisely something that provides the executable `/usr/bin/ssh-askpass`.

You already have installed `ssh-askpass-gnome`, but on your headless server, where it does not belong (and probably pulled in lots of dependencies for graphical applications which you would not want there).

You have to install it on your desktop client instead:

```
sudo apt install ssh-askpass-gnome
```

Comment: Totally agreeing to this answer, and in addition this is the reason that virt-manager has:

`Suggests: virt-viewer,` **ssh-askpass** `, gnome-keyring, gir1.2-secret-1, python-guestfs`